# Ruby on Rails Unique Ordered Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

What I am trying to do is:

- Find the most recent `CompetencyLog (completed_at)` for each `Competency` on a `Course` for a `Member`

  ```
  class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :competency_logs
    has_many :awards
  end

  class CompetencyLog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :member
    belongs_to :competency
    has_one :course, through: :competency
  end

  def Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :competencies
    has_many :awards
  end

  class Competency < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
  end
  ```

I have managed to get the ordered list

```
course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
current_member.competency_logs.where('competency_id IN (?)', course.competency_ids).ordered
```

From here I have tried a few different things with limited to no success. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Looking to do as much of this in the database as possible for speed since this is frequently called and depended on ever changing timestamps on the `CompetencyLog`

The results I want are basically

```
member.competency_logs.where('competency_id IN (?)', course.competency_ids).uniq.pluck(:competency_id)
```

But instead of the competency_id I want the competency_log models

---

So I've added some additional relationships and come up with the following so far, currently investigating postgresql `DISTINCT ON` as an alternative

```
competency_logs = competencies.collect { |c| c.competency_logs.ordered.first }
competency_logs.collect { |c| c.current? }.all?
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
max_completed = current_member.competency_logs.where('competency_id IN (?)', course.competency_ids).maximum(:completed_at)
current_member.competency_logs.first(:conditions => {:completed_at => max_completed})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response however this would not work. Each course has many `Competencies` and each `Competency` has many `CompetencyLogs` I need to get the latest `CompetencyLog` for each `Competency`

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem. It does however operate under the assumption that you don't have duplicated `completed_at` timestamps per member.

```
some_member.competency_logs.
  where(
    competency_id: some_course.competency_ids,
    completed_at: some_member.competency_logs.
                    select("MAX(completed_at) as completed_at").
                    where(competency_id: some_course.competency_ids).
                    group(:completed_at)
  )
```